# AM-GM inequality problems on 3 variables

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge0$. Prove that:

$$\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\ge4$$

This is a problem from Samin Riasat's Olympiad Inequalities worksheet. The worksheet gives a hint as to prove and use $$\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca\geq\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$
I've done it, substituted it in the original inequality and now I have to prove:

$$\frac{9\mathrm{AM}^2+3\mathrm{GM}^2}{3\mathrm{AM}\cdot\mathrm{GM}}\geq4$$

where $\mathrm{AM}$ and $\mathrm{GM}$ are the arithmetic and geometric means of $a$, $b$ and $c$. How can I finish the problem?

Comment: You can use uvw (also known as pqr) or just simplify and use Muirhead or something.

Comment: FYI. A stronger inequality is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4874438/elegant-proof-of-frac25-left-fracxy-fracyz-fraczx-right-f

Comment: Then let $x = \frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} \ge 3$ (by AM-GM), you want to prove  $x + 3/x \ge 4$ or $(x - 1)(x-3)/x \ge 0$ which is true.

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189143/proving-inequality-fracab-fracbc-fracca-frac3-sqrt3abca?noredirect=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703357/inequality-involving-am-gm-but-its-wierd?noredirect=1 or even https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185604/prove-inequality-fracab-fracbc-fracca-frac9-sqrt3abcab?noredirect=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764022/strange-cube-root-offense-in-an-inequality?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution.
Take the expression with AM and GM, it simplifies to $3\frac{AM}{GM}+\frac{GM}{AM}$. Now, since $AM\ge GM$, there exists $k \ge 1$ such that $AM=k\cdot GM$. Substituting in the inequality, we get $$3k+\frac1k \ge 4$$ Taking the derivative, we get $3-1/k^2$. For $k \ge 1$, the derivative is positive, so the minimum value of the expression for $k \ge 1$ is the value for $k=1$, which is $4$, and it finishes the problem.

Comment: Use mathjax pls

Comment: Simpler maybe $2AM/GM + (AM/GM +GM/AM)\geqslant 2+2$

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see this:-
$$a^3b^3c^3=(a^2c)(b^2a)(c^2b)=(abc)^3$$
So we can say from the second expression, using AM-GM inequality that:-

$$\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2b}{3}≥\sqrt[3]{(a^2c)(b^2a)(c^2b)}$$
Or
$$a^2c+b^2a+c^2b≥3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^3}$$
Or
$$\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2b}{abc}≥3...(i)$$

Again, by AM-GM inequality we know that:-
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}≥\sqrt[3]{abc}$$
Or
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}≥1$$
Or (By doing reciprocal)
$$\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}≤1$$ or
$$1≥\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}...(ii)$$

Adding (i) and (ii), we get
$$\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2b}{abc} + 1 ≥ 3 + \frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}$$
Or
$$\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2b}{abc}-\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}≥2$$
Adding $\frac{6\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}$ on both sides
$$\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2b}{abc}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}≥2+\frac{6\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}$$

But from $(ii)$, we know
$$2≥\frac{6\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}$$
Or
$$4≥2+\frac{6\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}$$

Hence
$$\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2b}{abc}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}≥4$$

I didn't use your hint somehow

Comment: If $P\geq Q$ and $4\geqslant Q$ that does not mean $P\geqslant 4$.  Your last step is faulty.

Comment: @Macavity The maximum value of Q is 4, while P is more than or equal to any value of Q, be it 4 or less. Can you give an example where this doesn't happen?  **Reply edit**:- Okay I got it. Q is not compulsorily 4. It can be less. Can you please provide some help?

Comment: This has been done multiple times at this site IIRC.  Will provide some links above.